# Dynamic Handlebars Master Template with Backend

Tags: node.js, express

used HBS as Template engine in my express app. This issue come when trying to display the title in dynamic page (details page).

My Controllers

```
exports.getProduct = (req, res, next) => {
    var prodId = req.params.productId;
    Product.findById(prodId)
    .then(([product]) => {
        res.render('shop/product-detail', { 
            product: product[0], 
            title: product.title 
        });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

My Layout

```
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>{{{ title }}}</title>
  </head>
```

My View

```
<div class="container">

<div class="card-deck">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="{{product.imageUrl}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">{{product.title}}</h5>
      <p class="card-text">{{product.description}}</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Rp {{product.price}}</small></p>
      <form action="/add-to-cart" method="POST">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block">Add to Cart</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="productId" value="{{product.id}}">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

In view the product title is working fine. But in the master template (layout) is not showing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

server side :  `title: product[0].title`

frontend side replace `<title>{{{ title }}}</title>` with

`<title>{{ title }}</title>`